# getOptimisticResponse is not working for fields with arguments

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay

Below is my code for adding and removing a person from a group.

For some reason, `getOptimisticResponse` is not working for this mutation.

Could this be due to having an argument `groupId` for `isInGroup` field?

```
class GroupAddRemovePersonMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  static initialVariables = {
    groupId: null,
  }

  static prepareVariables(prevVars) {
    return prevVars;
  }

  static fragments = {
    person: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Person {
        id
        isInGroup(groupId: $groupId)
      }
    `,
  }

  getMutation() {
    return this.props.isInGroup ?
      Relay.QL`mutation { groupRemovePerson }` :
      Relay.QL`mutation { groupAddPerson }`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    const {groupId, person} = this.props;
    return {
      personId: person.id,
      groupId,
    };
  }

  getCollisionKey() {
    const {groupId, person} = this.props;
    return `groupPerson_${groupId}_${person.id}`;
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    const {groupId, person, isInGroup} = this.props;
    return isInGroup ?
      Relay.QL`
        fragment on GroupRemovePersonMutationPayload {
          person {
            id
            groups { id }
            isInGroup(groupId: "${groupId}")
          }
          group {
            id
            person
            hasPerson(personId: "${person.id}")
          }
        }
      ` :
      Relay.QL`
        fragment on GroupAddPersonMutationPayload {
          person {
            id
            groups { id }
            isInGroup(groupId: "${groupId}")
          }
          group {
            id
            person
            hasPerson(personId: "${person.id}")
          }
        }
      `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    const {groupId, person} = this.props;
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        person: person.id,
        group: groupId,
      },
    }];
  }

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    const {groupId, person, isInGroup} = this.props;
    return {
      person: {
        id: person.id,
        isInGroup: !isInGroup,
      },
      group: {
        id: groupId,
        hasPerson: !isInGroup,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding the `groupId` to the optimistic response first. In my experience, the optimistic response has to match the shape of the fat query exactly.

If you don't have the groupIds at the time the optimistic response is generated, you could try substituting temporary values until the response is returned from the server. This scenario occurs often when you are rendering a connection and providing keys to the view to distinguish repeated React elements.